# Application crashes when selecting a different Spinner item

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a simple application that is supposed to display the information for a particular meal depending on the meal name selected by the user in the Spinner. The application fetches the meals correctly and the information for the first one is automatically displayed in the appropriate fields as intended. Basically, the application functions exactly like it is supposed to right up until the user tries to select a different item from the Spinner at which point the application crashes. What is particularly frustrating about this error is that it doesn't even show me what the error is in my Logcat, it just crashes. I cannot for the life of me seem to identify the problem here. In desperate need of help, any and all responses are greatly appreciated :)

Below is a copy of my code. Please ignore the comments and Toast messages, those are simply there for my own testing purposes.
PS. I am still quite new to working with Android Studio

```
package com.example.abc_supermarket;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class my_meals extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnMyProgress,
            btnProgressTracker,
            btnMealTracker,
            btnMyMeals,
            btnSettings;

    Button btnTester;

    EditText edtCalories, edtSugar, edtFat, edtCarbs, edtServings, edtMealType;
    ImageView imgMeal;
    Spinner spnMeals;

    ArrayList<meals> theMeals = new ArrayList<meals>();
    ArrayList<String> mealNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    String mealName;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    user theUser;
    MyApplication app;
    DatabaseReference dbRefBase, dbRef, dbRefBase2, dbRef2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_meals);

        app = (MyApplication)getApplication();
        theUser = app.theUser;

        dbRefBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        dbRef = dbRefBase.child("meals").child(theUser.username);

        //dbRef = dbRefBase.child("meals").child(theUser.username).child("burger");        this gets the name "burger" and adds it to the spinner as intended

        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    String currMealName = ds.getKey().toString();
                    mealNames.add(currMealName);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                dbRefBase2 = dbRefBase;
                Toast.makeText(my_meals.this, "RTEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for (int x = 0; x<mealNames.size(); ++x)
                {
                    dbRef2 = dbRefBase2.child("meals").child(theUser.username).child(mealNames.get(x).toString());

                    dbRef2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                            {
                                meals currMeal = new meals();
                                currMeal.name = ds.getValue(meals.class).name.toString();
                                currMeal.type = ds.getValue(meals.class).type.toString();
                                currMeal.servings = (int) ds.getValue(meals.class).servings;
                                currMeal.calories = (double) ds.getValue(meals.class).calories;
                                currMeal.carbs = (double) ds.getValue(meals.class).carbs;
                                currMeal.fat = (double) ds.getValue(meals.class).fat;
                                currMeal.sugar = (double) ds.getValue(meals.class).sugar;
                                theMeals.add(currMeal);
                                Toast.makeText(my_meals.this, theMeals.get(theMeals.size()-1).name.toUpperCase(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    //THIS SHOWS WHAT IT IS SUPPOSED TO
                                //MEAL OBJECTS ARE GETTING SAVED CORRECTLY
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        initComps();
        navbarListeners();


        //at this point we have all meal names stored in the spinner as intended


        spnMeals.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(my_meals.this, spnMeals.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      this displays the correct meal name
                getMealInfo();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                spnMeals.setSelection(0);
            }
        });

    }


    protected void getMealInfo()
    {
        boolean imageFlag = false, infoFlag = false;
        int k = 0;
        meals currMeal;
        mealName = spnMeals.getSelectedItem().toString();
        for (int x = 0; x < theMeals.size(); ++x)
        {
            while (!infoFlag)
            {
                if ((theMeals.get(x).name).equals(mealName))
                {
                    infoFlag = true;
                    meals meal = (meals) theMeals.get(x);
                    edtCalories.setText(Double.toString(meal.calories));
                    edtSugar.setText(Double.toString(meal.sugar));
                    edtFat.setText(Double.toString(meal.fat));
                    edtCarbs.setText(Double.toString(meal.carbs));
                    edtServings.setText(Integer.toString(meal.servings));
                    edtMealType.setText(meal.type);

                    while ((!imageFlag) && (k < app.usermeals.size()))
                    {
                        currMeal = app.usermeals.get(k);
                        if (currMeal.name.equals(theMeals.get(x).name))
                        {
                            imageFlag = true;
                            imgMeal.setImageBitmap(currMeal.image);
                        }
                        ++k;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void initComps()
    {
                btnMyProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmmMyProgress);
                btnProgressTracker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmmProgressTracker);
                btnMealTracker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmmMealTracker);
                btnMyMeals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmmMyMeals);
                btnSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmmSettings);

                edtCalories = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtmCalories);
                edtSugar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtmSugar);
                edtFat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtmFat);
                edtCarbs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtmCarbs);
                edtServings = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtmServings);
                edtMealType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtmMealType);

                spnMeals = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnMealSelect);

                imgMeal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgMeal);

        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(my_meals.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mealNames);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnMeals.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well without error log it's little difficult to resolve the issue.
you can use try-catch blocks catch the exception(errors) and know why app is crashing.
and You can also toast the exception in catch block so you can get exception detail in app.

As it comes to your code and based on your description of issue might be problem in
`protected void getMealInfo()`
add try catch blocks and get the error.

Based on error we can resolve it.

Comment: I have tried that but the program does not seem to catch the exception in the catch block as it does not display anything in the toast message.

Comment: What I don't understand is that the getMealInfo() method works fine for the first item as stated and displays the correct info but not for the other items in the spinner

Comment: in `onCreate` method add this `initComps();` before `dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()` this line instead of after.
May be this is dummy (wrong) solutions some times these might work i had such problems and encountered with this type of solution. Some times it worked for me and some time i made other mistakes.